# How to Use OuterRef for ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to query a list of rooms. There can be many participants in the rooms. I want to exclude rooms where there are participants a user blocked or got blocked from. The below code works if participants are simple ForeignKey(User) fields. However, the thing is participants are `ManyToManyField` field. It is written like

```py
participants = models.ManyToManyField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='participants'
)
```

And the below code does not work.

```py
get_blocked = Exists(
    users_models.Relationship.objects.filter(
        from_user=OuterRef('participants'), 
        to_user=info.context.user, 
        status='BLOCK',
    )
)
blocking = Exists(
    users_models.Relationship.objects.filter(
        from_user=info.context.user, 
        to_user=OuterRef('participants'), 
        status='BLOCK',
    )
)
models.Room.objects.annotate(
    get_blocked=get_blocked, blocking=blocking
).filter(
    participants=info.context.user, get_blocked=False, blocking=False
).distinct()
```

Again, the same logic works when the participants are simple ForeignKey(User). I am wondering if there is any way to resolve this issue.